# Merging three numpy arrays as jpeg image in python

Tags: python, numpy, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I have split a jpeg image into r,g,b and I converted them into numpy arrays. Then I changed the pixel values of r,g,b. Now I want to merge these three into one jpeg and save it. My original image is a 1024 * 500 image. If someone can give me an idea, it will be a great help

```
im =Image.open("new_image.jpg")
r,g,b=im.split()

r=np.array(r)
g=np.array(g)
b=np.array(b)
```

Then I changed the values of the pixels. I want to merge the resulting r,g,b. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

To convert a PIL Image to a NumPy array:

```
img = Image.open(FILENAME).convert('RGB')
arr = np.array(img)
r, g, b = arr[:,:,0], arr[:,:,1], arr[:,:,2]
...
```

To convert `r`, `g`, `b` (2-dimensional) NumPy arrays of dtype uint8 to a PIL Image:

```
arr = np.dstack([r, g, b])
img = Image.fromarray(arr, 'RGB')
```

---

This works because `Image.fromarray` can create a PIL Image from any object that supports the [NumPy array interface](http://effbot.org/zone/pil-changes-116.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [document](http://www.pythonware.com/media/data/pil-handbook.pdf) (page 4 in the end), you can do this with merge:

```
r, g, b = im.split()
im = Image.merge("RGB", (b, g, r))
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried that already. But it's not working.